# How to upload images from gallery to a supporting files in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am a newbie to iOS and I have given a task of creating a small app, which allows user to select image from the gallery and selected image gets  displayed in the UIImage view and should get saved in images folder under supporting files.

Currently image gets saved under documents folder, using following block of code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
self.imageView.image = image;
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

How can I save selected image under image folder in supporting files?

[Following is the folder structure in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDrHQ.png)

Comment: You __Cannot__ save an image to your project folder. Your project folder is what you have before you build your app. At runtime, all you have available for storage is the documents folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image can be able to save in the phone memory not in the images folder what you have, If you want to save the image with in your project you can able to save through core data or sqlite database but you cannot see the image in your images folder.

Am not sure why you need to show that on the images folder but its not possible i think according to my knowledge.

Based on your requirement which is given by you on comment I have edited my previous answer.

```
   MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
   mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
   [mail setSubject:@"find attachment"];
   UIImage *selectedImage = "put your image from your image view/ selected gallery image"
   NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImage);
   [mail addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"coolImage.png"];

   // set email body
   NSString *emailBody = @"My cool image is attached";
   [mail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
   [self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
```

All the best

Comment: Actually I want to attach selected image to mail sending function as an attachment.
when I try following code:
 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"savedImage" ofType:@"png"];
 NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
both returns nil.

Comment: I have edited my answer on how to add the selected image in attachment, check this out , If you still found the issue let me know , I will help you out on how to send the email attachment

Comment: @user5247057 , did you find the solution? let me know if the above answer will help you

Comment: @user5247057 ,Conversation is useless if you don't react to my questions